# how to get control of window? (Qt, Windows & Linux)

Tags: qt

I have two apps, created using Qt. One app suppose to get control of window from second app.
I get the handle (WId) of that window and now I want to get control. Is there any way (maybe some other library helps with it) to do it? 
It should work on Windows and Linux.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to bring it to the front? Send commands to it? Integrate it into your app? You'll need to define control a bit more clearly.

Comment: I want to get control of it to add some widgets to that window (by setting that window as a child of the window from first app)

Comment: You probably want to look at IPC rather than window control, getting the WId is easy enough but trying to add additional controls is difficult without actually going through the applications UI management, especially if you're trying to change it into a child window of another application.